# Accessing FormArray in nested FormGroup to create dynamically

Tags: angular

I am trying to figure out how to access this FormArray in a nested FormGroup in order to default fill and dynamically create the form groups. I want to create my form where its value's data structure will mimic the incoming data. I am currently getting the following error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'costs -> 0'

I have tried "flattening" the nested FormGroup, but then I do not get the correct output value as it is missing the nested "items" object. I have commented that code in the below StackBlitz.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6lvano

Data

```
{
    "type": "Transportation",
    "costs": {
      "items": [
        {
          "category": "Land",
          "name": "Taxi",
          "amount": 50
        },
        {
          "category": "Land",
          "name": "Train",
          "amount": 500
        },
        {
          "category": "Air",
          "name": "Plane",
          "amount": 500
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

Component

```
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  invoiceForm: FormGroup;
  get costs(): FormArray {
    // return this.invoiceForm.get('costs') as FormArray;
    return this.invoiceForm.get('costs.items') as FormArray;
  }
  
  data =  {
    "type": "Transportation",
    "costs": {
      "items": [
        {
          "category": "Land",
          "name": "Taxi",
          "amount": 50
        },
        {
          "category": "Land",
          "name": "Train",
          "amount": 500
        },
        {
          "category": "Air",
          "name": "Plane",
          "amount": 500
        },
      ]
    }
  };

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let items = FormArray[10] = [];
    if (this.data) {
      for (const cost of this.data.costs.items) {
        items.push(this.buildExpenseItem(cost.category, cost.name, cost.amount));
      }
    } else {
      items = [ this.buildExpenseItem() ];
    }
    
    this.invoiceForm = this.fb.group({
      type: [''],
      // costs: this.fb.array(items)
      costs: this.fb.group({ items: this.fb.array(items) })
    });
  }

  buildExpenseItem(category?: string, name?: string, amount?: number): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      category: [category],
      name: [name],
      amount: [amount]
    });
  }

  addExpenseItem() {
    this.costs.push(this.buildExpenseItem());
  }

  displayOutput() {
    console.log(this.invoiceForm.value);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<h1>Invoices</h1>

<form [formGroup]="invoiceForm">
  <ng-container formArrayName="costs">
    <div *ngFor="let cost of costs.controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        {{ i }}
        <input formControlName="category" placeHolder="Category">
        <input formControlName="name" placeHolder="Name">
        <input formControlName="amount" placeHolder="Amount">
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <button (click)="addExpenseItem()">Add</button>
</form>

<button (click)="displayOutput()">Display</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form [formGroup]="invoiceForm">
  <ng-container formArrayName="costs">
    <form formGroupName="items">
    <div *ngFor="let cost of costs.controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        {{ i }}
        <input formControlName="category" placeHolder="Category">
        <input formControlName="name" placeHolder="Name">
        <input formControlName="amount" placeHolder="Amount">
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </ng-container>

  <button (click)="addExpenseItem()">Add</button>
</form>
```

url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rvracc

Here we having two formGroup: **invoiceForm** and **items**

Hence, added: `<form formGroupName="items">`